# Setup antlr ide and antlr package

Tags: java, c, eclipse, compiler-construction, antlr

I have to create a c compiler. For that i am trying to use ANTLR in eclipse, I installed Antlr ide, but when i try to ANTLR package, it shows error as

> Invalid ANTLR home
>   Reason:
>   couldn't create a package

Please help me with the steps to install antlr package to use antlr grammar.

I tried with KEPLER, Galileo and with indigo eclipse too. No use, Please help me I am trying this for more than a week.

Comment: No answers even after 2 days. feel sad. Please some one help me.

Answer (score 1):

Follow the Steps provide on [Github repository](https://github.com/jknack/antlr4ide) and use Kepler It works for me

Answer (score 0):

Basic steps to setup ANTLR into the eclipse :
1) Goto Help -> Install new software
  Install :
    Dynamic Language Toolkit  from indigo -
             http://download.eclipse.org/releases/indigo/
    Under “General Purpose Tool” , check “Dynamic Language Toolkit” & install it
3) search and install ANTLR 4 IDE from Eclipse Marketplace
4) search and install ANTLR IDE v2.1.2  from  Eclipse Marketplace
5) Restart the eclipse to install the updates. If error persists with the hello world demo then restart the browser again.
6) You are all set.